# Sliding Windowed Grouped Aggregation

Tags: apache-spark, aggregate, spark-structured-streaming

I have pasted a screenshot from Spark Structured Streaming [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations-on-event-time).

My question is when I perform the actual count, am I not getting incorrect total count? For example, let's I perform a count at 12:10. I want to find out how many owls are there. Based on the diagram below I will get 2 owls, where in reality only 1 owl came in.

[image]

The above is a sliding window aggregation where you are aggregating based on event time and word columns.

Answer (score 0):

In the world of streaming, aggregates (and other stateful operators, like joins) change over time. At precisely 12:10, consider what records you've received so far:

- 12:02: `cat dog`
- 12:03: `dog dog`
- 12:07: `owl cat`

So, if you do a `.count()` after splitting by space, you do, in fact, only have 1 owl. This is reflected in the middle green box, which shows 1 owl for both of the sliding windows.

However, at 12:13, you receive `owl`. This means that any `.count()` *after* 12:13 will take into account this second owl. So, if we run a `.count()` at 12:15 pm (as in the diagram), 2 owls are around: the one at 12:07, and the one at 12:13. This leads to the following:

- The 12:00 to 12:10 window has one owl (the 12:07 one)
- The 12:05 to 12:15 window has two owls (the 12:07 and 12:13 one)
- The 12:10 to 12:20 window has one owl (the 12:13 one)